# Which method I should Use while using plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, tax, pdf

I am trying to override the `Tax` class from `Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf`. for these, I followed the below procedure.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax" type="ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax" />

</config>
```

**Tax.php**

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf;

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax{


    /**
     * Check if tax amount should be included to grandtotal block
     * array(
     *  $index => array(
     *      'amount'   => $amount,
     *      'label'    => $label,
     *      'font_size'=> $font_size
     *  )
     * )
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $store = $this->getOrder()->getStore();
        if ($this->_taxConfig->displaySalesTaxWithGrandTotal($store)) {
            return [];
        }

        $totals = [];
        $isValidAmount = false;
        $tempTotal =  array();
        $tempETotal = array();
        if ($this->_taxConfig->displaySalesFullSummary($store)) {
            $totals = $this->getFullTaxInfo();
            $tempAmount = parent::getTotalsForDisplay();
            foreach($totals as $t){
                $tempTaxAmount = $tempAmount[0]['amount']/2;
                $tempTaxAmount = number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.','');
                $SAmount = number_format($t['amount'],2,'.','');
                if($tempTaxAmount == $SAmount){
                    $isValidAmount = true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    $isValidAmount = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!$isValidAmount){
                $tempETotal = $totals;
                //Change the totals according to IGST
                $tempTaxAmount = $tempAmount[0]['amount']/2;
                foreach($tempETotal as $t){
                    $tempTotal[] = array(
                        'amount' => number_format("$tempTaxAmount",2,'.',''),
                        'label' => $t['label'],
                        'font_size' => $t['font_size'],
                        'percent' => number_format($t['percent'],2,'.',''),
                        'title' => $t['title'],
                        'tax_amount' => number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.',''),
                        'base_tax_amount' => number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.','')
                    );
                }
                unset($totals);
                $totals = $tempTotal;
            }
        }

        $totals = array_merge($totals, parent::getTotalsForDisplay());

        return $totals;
    }


}
```

Above code is working perfectly when written in the core module. I know that is a bad idea, so I have overwritten my module it's executing but calculations are not working correctly.

So I decided to use `plugin` to restrict executing core code for this I followed below one.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax">
        <plugin name="OverWritePdfTax" type="ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**Tax.php**

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf;

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax{

/**
     * Check if tax amount should be included to grandtotal block
     * array(
     *  $index => array(
     *      'amount'   => $amount,
     *      'label'    => $label,
     *      'font_size'=> $font_size
     *  )
     * )
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetTotalsForDisplay($result)
    {
        $returnValue = $result;
    }

}
```

Here I struck how to proceed my logic. Can anyone help me to implement logic to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `afterGetTotalsForDisplay()`, you will **get total only**. So if you want to apply your login on total you can apply it on **$returnValue** but if you want to apply your logic when total is being calculated you can use **around Plugin** instead of after plugin.

Comment: Got it. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: Ronak, In my local system working fine in my live website returning empty `Array()`. i.e. `callable $proceed` parameter from `public function aroundGetTotalsForDisplay(\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax $tax, callable $proceed)` function. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Any suggestion need to change my code?

Comment: Any suggestion https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206480/plug-in-not-working-in-live-environment-in-magento-2

Comment: Proceed will not return you anything...only result will return, but around function will call when core function will be called so just apply your code and don't call proceed  return your total

Comment: Created new thread with full of code please suggest me .https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206480/plug-in-not-working-in-live-environment-in-magento-2