# Plugin not working in live environment in Magento 2

Tags: tax, magento-2.1.3, pdf

I have overwritten the `Tax` class for **IGST** calculation customization. It's working fine on my local system. After I uploaded the live server it's not working, I don't know where anything I missed.

For this stuff, I have written below logic.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax">
        <plugin name="OverWritePdfTax" type="ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Tax.php**

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\IGST\Model\Sales\Pdf;

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax{

    public function aroundGetTotalsForDisplay(\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax $tax, callable $proceed)
    {
        $totals = [];
        $totals = $proceed();

        $isValidAmount = false;
        $tempTotal =  array();
        $tempETotal = array();
        $tempI = 0;
        $totalCount = count($totals) - 1;
        $tempTaxAmount = 0;
        $tempAmount = 0;

        foreach($totals as $t){
            if($totalCount == $tempI){
                $tempTaxAmount = $t['amount']/2;
                $tempTaxAmount = number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.','');
                $tempAmount = number_format($t['amount'],2,'.','');
            }
            $tempI++;
        }

        foreach($totals as $t){
            if(($t['title'] == "SGST") || ($t['title'] == "CGST")){
                $SAmount = number_format($t['amount'],2,'.','');
                if($tempTaxAmount == $SAmount){
                    $isValidAmount = true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    $isValidAmount = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!$isValidAmount){
            $tempETotal = $totals;
            //Change the totals according to IGST
            $tempTaxAmount = $tempAmount/2;
            foreach($tempETotal as $t){
                if(isset($t['title'])){
                    if(($t['title'] == "SGST") || ($t['title'] == "CGST")){

                        $tempTotal[] = array(
                            'amount' => number_format("$tempTaxAmount",2,'.',''),
                            'label' => $t['label'],
                            'font_size' => $t['font_size'],
                            'percent' => number_format($t['percent'],2,'.',''),
                            'title' => $t['title'],
                            'tax_amount' => number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.',''),
                            'base_tax_amount' => number_format($tempTaxAmount,2,'.','')
                        );
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isset($t['label'])){
                        if($t['label'] == "Tax:"){
                            $tempTotal[] = array(
                                'amount' => number_format($t['amount'],2,'.',''),
                                'label' => $t['label'],
                                'font_size' => $t['font_size']
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           unset($totals);
           $totals = $tempTotal;
        }
        return $totals;
    }

}
```

Here `$totals = $proceed();` it's returning the `$total` value i.e **SGST,CGST and Tax** in local system.

After successfully working I deployed the live server it's not working. When I debug the code `$totals = $proceed();` returning empty `Array()`.

I don't know why it's not working.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you call proceed means you are calling core method. So if you want to apply login on total before it calculated then without calling core procees apply your logic and return total.

> > Note: Remove $totals = $proceed();

For more guidance you can refer [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Then how can? give an example of code to do this.

Comment: copy code of core function and put it in your function! and don't call proceed(), now you can place your logic in between that code.

Comment: It's returning error `Call to undefined method Magento\Tax\Model\ResourceModel\Sales\Order\Tax\Collection::getOrder()` at the starting of the method. Can you please suggest me how to do?

Comment: Use `$tax` instead of `$this` when you call core methods

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: Again throwing error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\yumwareh\vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\Sales\Pdf\Tax.php on line 46` in First line.

Comment: hey if you just want to add extra value in total then you can use after plugin as I told you

Comment: you are not calculating total, you are just adding value into total right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70553/discussion-between-magento-two-and-ronak-chauhan).